# Can I use B1 visa to travel to any US state without a business purpose?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel, honduran-citizens

I recently got my B1 visa in Honduras for training purposes to Miami. My visa is only for 3 months and will expire in Dec 4th, 2014. It also has the name and address of the company in my passport.

I spoke to my boss and he said it was not necessary that I go to the training and that I could use my visa for vacations. My concern is the name and address in my passport.  I have family in Las Vegas and would really love to spend Thanksgiving with them.

Can I travel to another state that is not Miami, FL?

Comment: The reality is that even when you really are engaged in business it's unlikely to be 24/7.  For someone on a business visa to engage in some tourism is normal.

Answer (score 3):

If you are legally in the United States, there are no restrictions (based on visa rules) to you traveling from state to state. (TBH, if you are illegally in the US, there are no restrictions either.) There are no border crossings between states, and in fact, if not for the mile markers and Welcome To X signs, you'll likely never know you go from one to another.

Comment: but I am currently in Honduras... am I able to buy my ticket to Miami, FL round trip and buy another ticket from Miami, FL to Las Vegas and come back to Miami, FL to come back to Honduras?

Comment: There is no problem with what you describe.  Yes, you can buy any number of "internal" tickets, no problem. It makes no difference if you buy them "now" or "only when you are there" etc. Enjoy!

Comment: Once you have entered, you can fly all the to Hawaii and back without needing a visa as its all one big country :)

Comment: While there are no restrictions on someone who is here illegally moving around a foreigner is going to have to use their passport for ID at security and there's a small but non-zero chance a snoopy document checker notes that you're out of status.  Illegals generally only get caught when they have a brush with law enforcement for some other reason or else because immigration raids their workplace.